# What is this executable file named "Icon?" doing in my applications folder (and other folders)?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

Is this file a malware? Anyone know why these unix executables keep appearing in my folders? This is a fresh installation of macOS High Sierra.

[image: Strange unix executable named Icon?]

[image]

Comment: Do you use the app DeClutter?  I seem to have Icon? in every folder from DeClutter.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not malware. These are often found which you create manual application icons by copying and pasting images from the Info menu.

Heres an Apple Script Application I made with a custom icon from Google.

[image]

### [image]

Not sure why its there but its probably safe to delete and wont cause any harm if you don't.